Custom Implicit Conversion in Kotlin
In C# I can create my own implicit conversion for my classes as follows...
public static implicit operator TypeYouWantToChangeTo (ClassYouAreChanging c)  
{ 
    TypeYouWantToChangeTo x;
    //convert c to x
    return x;
}

How do you make a class be able to implicitly convert to another class? Also in C# I can change implicit to explicit to also create the ability to cast manually. How do you accomplish this in Kotlin?

Kotlin doesn’t have implicit conversions

My (limited) experience with Scala suggests that untrammeled implicit conversions can be highly counter-intuitive, and cause problems that are really hard to track down.  Kotlin tends to make such things much more explicit, which can avoid subtle bugs and other unexpected effects.  (It even requires explicit conversions between primitive types, which can be a little annoying but on balance is a lot safer.)  But in my experience, there's much less need for implicit conversions in idiomatic Kotlin.  Do you have a particular use case in mind?

Implicit conversions doesn't exist in Kotlin. The most used convention for doing conversions is creating a function called toX(), where X is the type you are converting to.
For example like this:
fun ClassYouAreChanging.toTypeYouWantToChangeTo(): TypeYouWantToChangeTo { 
    //convert this to x
    return x;
}

If the conversion is just a cast or if it creates a view backed by the original object, the convention is to name the method asX() instead.
